# How to fill-in an UItableview after extracting data with a function?

Tags: swift, uitableview, alamofire, swift5

I have troubles while filling-in the cells of my table view :

I would like to fill-in the cells once the function Fetch() finished runned, then the arrayComponents is filled by the informations I would like to display in my cells :

```
var arrayComponents:Array<String> = Array(repeating: "", count: 4)

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayComponents.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel!.text = arrayComponents[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageView!.image = image

    return cell
}

func fetch(jan: String){

                    self.fetchAll { result in
                        switch result {
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print(error)

                        case .success(let values):
                            self.arrayData = values

                            self.arrayComponents = ["\(self.arrayData[1])","\(self.arrayData[2])","\(self.arrayData[3])","\(self.arrayData[4])"]

                        }
                    }
                }

        case .failure(let error):
            print("\(error) in fetch")
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetch(jan: dataFromFirst)

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

}
```

}

How can I load the table view once the fetch() finished and returned the values ?

Comment: `tableView.reloadData()` Note that all collections in Swift are zero based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Reload your tableView data after fetching*

```
   func fetch(jan: String){

        self.fetchAll { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
              print(error)

        case .success(let values):
             self.arrayData = values
             self.arrayComponents = ["\(self.arrayData[1])","\(self.arrayData[2])","\(self.arrayData[3])","\(self.arrayData[4])"]

                    }
                }
       //Reload data

       tableView.reloadData()

        }
```